# Scapy sending multiple packets when only one is specified

Tags: python, scapy

I'm sending a simple ARP request using Scapy. I noticed that it will send multiple packets out though, even when I've only given it a single packet:

```
from scapy.sendrecv import sr1
from scapy.layers.l2 import ARP
from typing import Optional

def request_mac(target_ip: str, **kwargs) -> Optional[str]:
    req = ARP(pdst=target_ip)
    reply = sr1(req, **kwargs)
    return reply and reply[ARP].hwsrc

request_mac("192.168.123.118", timeout=5)
```

In Wireshark, I can see that it sends out two ARPs instead of one:

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Even though the output only shows one being sent:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
................................................................................................................
Received 112 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

If I set the `retry` parameter to `sr1`, I get two packets sent for every one I explicitly send.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to have it only send one? When I made a port scanner, I didn't see duplicate sends of TCP segments, so it seems like it may be specific to ARPs?

Comment: I've been able to replicate this on Macos/Linux *provided that the ARP packet is sent in your subnet*. The 2nd packet is sent 2 seconds after the first. This is a problem with both `sr` and `sr1`.

Comment: @RossJacobs Yes, it's about a two second delay between them for me as well. And I'm on Windows.

Comment: I'd add an issue on github.com/secdev/scapy. If you need something that works, just use `scapy.layers.l2.arping`.

Comment: @RossJacobs Oh, thanks. It isn't a *huge* deal, there just may be circumstances when I want to limit the traffic that I produce.

Comment: It turns out it does the same thing with ICMP packets, which messes up using `sr` with packet sets. I get duplicate replies instead of a reply for each request.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report? If this isn't buggy behavior, this is at least *unexpected* behavior, per docs.

Comment: @RossJacobs I forgot to earlier. [Submitted now](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2831).

Comment: @RossJacobs I hate to ping you like this is some kind of chatroom, but out of curiosity, I figured out that I can fix the double sending by disabling IP Forwarding. Do you have IP Forwarding enabled on the computer that you were able to reproduce it on? I noticed that the TTL of the duplicate message is one lower than the first. I think my computer is sending it out of two interfaces, then routing the second message back and decrementing the TTL, or something.

Comment: I’m running it on a macbook, so nope. I’ve also verified it on an ubuntu vps.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea. The decremented  TTLs suggest that one packet is being routed before it's sent, but I can't tell why.

Comment: ...why do you have TTLs on an ARP packet?

Comment: @RossJacobs I'm writing a `traceroute` program now, so I'm using ICMPs, not ARPs. Same behavior though.

Comment: Perhaps post that code in your question as an edit?

Comment: I updated the bug report with my new findings. If this is a bug in Scapy, then this should just be closed, or answered once the bug is confirmed. The ping can be reproduced via `sr(IP(dst=destination_ip, ttl=hop_n) / ICMP())` though.

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly extraneous ARP traffic. Because the `X.X.X.118` in your picture != `X.X.X.123` in your code.

As an example, when I run your code, I get exactly one request, and then various arp requests on the network

[image: ![ARP requests]

In my capture, I see ARP requests for 192.168.128.5 every second from the upstream firewall.

Comment: Whoops, the `.123` in my question was a remnant from a previous edit. In the code that generated the output, I am using `.118`. Odd though that you can't reproduce it.